# Getting PDF to stay in an embedded <object> or <iframe>

Tags: html, css, pdf

*I've edited this quite a bit and bolded my question at this point.  I realize that PDF won't be fully controllable in the browser, but that's not my issue here.  My problem is, well, below in bold.*

```
<div>
    <object 
        data="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/UB04.xml" 
        type="application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml" 
        width="415" height="500"/>
</div>
```

The XML is actually an XDP file; it gives dynamic data and a URL for a static PDF, and combines them in Adobe Reader.  This displays in the browser as desired if it's a PDF, but when put in as an XDP, it takes control of the window and opens itself fullscreen to display the PDF.  Serving an all-in-one XDP (with the PDF embedded as base64) has the same issue.

***Help me make the XDP behave the same as a PDF?***

Alternatively, if I can use iText to glue together the XDP XML and the static PDF template, I can serve the PDF directly, which seems to work just fine.  Just not sure how to create PDF that route, which is somewhat underwhelmingly documented online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: use iText to join the data into the PDF, skipping XDP entirely.

Comment: I used Adobe LiveCycle to convert the XDP into a PDF.  This seems to work well, and I have no problems with embedding a PDF as an <object>.  I've added a few options to the PDF's URL to control how it displays well enough to meet my needs: filename.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&zoom=100

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is dictated by the user agent (client), and that is how it should remain.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, any suggested workarounds?  I can easily do this if the extension is PDF, but when producing PDF via XDP, that isn't a workaround I can use here.

Comment: No.  Even if it was working as expected in your development environment, you can be assured that there will be plenty of users that have a different experience (because of their different settings).  As a general rule of thumb, I don't bother with things like this because it makes sense for the client to be in control this behavior.  I wouldn't have it any other way.

Comment: TBH I really wish people would stop trying to embed PDF in web pages. It's a usability horror and having to have the Reader plugin installed has proved to be a security disaster. Please just give us a link to a PDF file and be done with it.

Comment: For what my client wants, this is absolutely the best approach.  Doing pixel-perfect layouts using AJAX is a distant second, because it's much easier (from our experience) to make pixel-perfect PDF.

Comment: Then you will need to accept the fact that a PDF document is *not* a web page.

Comment: *I can embed a PDF without a problem.* I can't seem to embed XDP, and am wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is called Adobe Flashpaper:
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/examples/

Otherwise you cannot dictate how the user will view the PDF.

Comment: If I put the PDF directly into an iframe, it seems to work just fine on half a dozen different users machines here.  If I put XDP/PDF into the iframe or object, no dice.

Comment: As mentioned above, your milage will vary based on user settings, so you CANNOT dictate how they will display it, thats why Adobe created Flashpaper, so you CAN.

Comment: Which user settings?  If I could turn this off in a browser, that would be enough; I have an unusually high level of user control on this one.